# Find matching cell with different strings inside one cell

Tags: vba, excel, loops, string-matching

My goal of my macro:

I have 2 sheets, `sheet1` master report and `sheet2` import Input.

In column A of both sheets I have several strings in one cell.
I would like to see if there is a match and if there is the match the row from sheet2 (from column B) will be copied and paste in the row corresponding in sheet1.

1. This part of my code is done.
   But now it starts to be tricky: If there is new string in the same cell as the matching string so I would like to add them as well in the cell of the column A `sheet1`.

For instance:

```
Sheet1 Column A Cell34:
MDM-9086

Sheet2 Column A Cell1:
MDM-9086,MDM-12345
```

After the macro it would be like this:

```
Sheet1 Column A cell34:
MDM-9086,MDM-12345
```

2. If there is no match between column A of both sheets so I would like to copy the entire row of the sheet2 and past it in the last free row of the `sheet1`.

See my code:

```
Sub MDMNumbers()
Dim LastRw1 As Long, LastRw2 As Long, NxtRw As Long
Dim I As Integer
Dim m As Range
Dim Tb

LastRw1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
LastRw2 = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets(2)
    LastRw2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For NxtRw = 2 To LastRw2

        Tb = Split(.Range("A" & NxtRw), ",")

            For I = 0 To UBound(Tb)

                With Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & LastRw1)


                    Set m = .Find(Trim(Tb(I)), LookAt:=xlPart)

                    If Not m Is Nothing Then

                    Sheets(2).Range("B" & NxtRw & ":Q" & NxtRw).Copy _
                    Sheets(1).Range("B" & m.Row)

                    Set m = Nothing

                End If

            End With

        Next I

    Next NxtRw

End With
End Sub
```

---

Example:

Sheet 1, Column A (start row 2)

```
MDM-123,MDM-27827
MDM-1791728,MDM-124
MDM-125
MDM-126,MDM-28920
MDM-127,MDM-1008
""
```

Sheet 2, Column A (start row 2)

```
MDM-123,MDM-27272
MDM-124
MDM-125,MDM-1289
MDM-126
MDM-1008
MDM-127
MDM-172891
```

---

**Result** on Sheet 1, Column A (start row 2):

```
MDM-123,MDM-27827,MDM-27272
MDM-124,MDM-1791728
MDM-125,MDM-1289
MDM-126,MDM-28920
MDM-127,MDM-1008
MDM-1008
MDM-172891
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your # 2.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MDMNumbers()

    Dim LastRw1 As Long, LastRw2 As Long, NxtRw As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim i As Long, m As Range, tb() As String, celVal As String, notFound As Boolean
    Dim additions1 As String, additions2 As String

    LastRw1 = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Worksheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRw2 = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & Worksheets(2).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    notFound = True

    For NxtRw = 2 To LastRw2
        celVal = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & NxtRw).Value2

        If Len(celVal) > 0 Then
            tb = Split(celVal, ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(tb)
                Set m = Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Find(Trim(tb(i)), LookAt:=xlPart)
                If Not m Is Nothing And notFound Then
                    Set rng1 = Worksheets(2).Range("B" & NxtRw & ":Q" & NxtRw)
                    Set rng2 = Worksheets(1).Range("B" & m.Row & ":Q" & m.Row)
                    rng1.Copy rng2

                    With Worksheets(2).Range("A" & NxtRw)
                        additions1 = Replace(.Value2, "," & tb(i), vbNullString)
                        additions1 = Replace(additions1, tb(i) & ",", vbNullString)
                        additions1 = Replace(additions1, tb(i), vbNullString)
                    End With

                    With Worksheets(1).Range("A" & m.Row)
                        additions2 = Replace(.Value2, "," & tb(i), vbNullString)
                        additions2 = Replace(additions2, tb(i) & ",", vbNullString)
                        additions2 = Replace(additions2, tb(i), vbNullString)

                        If Len(additions2) > 0 Then
                            If Len(additions1) > 0 Then
                                .Value2 = tb(i) & "," & additions2 & "," & additions1
                            Else
                                .Value2 = tb(i) & "," & additions2
                            End If
                        Else
                            .Value2 = tb(i) & "," & additions1
                        End If
                    End With
                    Set m = Nothing
                    notFound = False
                End If
            Next
            If notFound Then
                Set rng1 = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & NxtRw & ":Q" & NxtRw)
                Set rng2 = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & LastRw1 & ":Q" & LastRw1)
                rng1.Copy rng2
                LastRw1 = LastRw1 + 1
            End If
            notFound = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

It should work as expected now

Test data and result:

[image: TestResult]

Comment: That's perfect!!! However 
In the case of:

ColumnA sheet2 cell10: MDM-100,MDM-32

ColumnA sheet1 cell20: MDM-100

Result:
ColumnA sheet1 cell20: MDM-100 (and the row will update as i want)
But it will add in the last row of sheet columnA:
MDM-100,MDM-32
In this case i don't want another line but just to update the ColumnA sheet1 cell20 such as: MDM-100,MDM-32

Comment: It's hard to read your un-formatted requirements in the comments: can you update your question to include all rows in Sheet1 and Sheet2, that will cover your cases (I'll reformat your answer if needed). Just show about 10 values in Sheet1.Column1, and the same for Sheet2, columns 1, 2, 3...

Comment: In a nutshell if there is a match in one string inside a cell from sheet2 to sheet1 so all new strings from sheet2 has to update the cell matched in sheet1 columnA. If no match so new lines.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think I got it - I updated my answer; please try it and let me know if it works. Also, please remove your answers: you were trying to be helpful, but the details you provided in the 2 answers should have been placed as edits to your own question (or "original post" = OP) to provide complete and clear requirements

Comment: 1)If there is no match, the new line is added correctly.
2) However there is no update in the sheet1 A when there is new strings (MDM) in the sheet2 A.
But the row is copy/paste correctly.

Comment: Ok, I'll update your question to show you how to present your test data, then you can update my edit to provide the data you are using

Comment: I understand now (from your last comment): if Sheet2.ColumnA string is found in Sheet1.ColumnA, but it contains extra text you want to also update Sheet1.ColumnA value

Comment: Yes it is exactly what i would like to have. And if not found it goes to the last free row in sheet1 as you have already done perfectly.

Comment: Now in sheet1 A copie exactly what it is in sheet2 A. What i would like is that cells in sheet1 A, remain fixed, I mean strings inside cannot be erased. It can only be updated by new strings from sheet2 A.

Comment: I have your test data, and I see what you want. I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: I just notice something. When there is no match so the notFound, it takes only the last line of the sheet2 instead of taking any line without match in the sheet2 A.

Comment: It works perfectly, you rock!!! I don't know how to thank you!
Everything works how it is suppose to be.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I made it so it will provide the functionality you need, but it can be optimized if you work with large files. Just remember when you ask questions to provide the data you work with, and the expected result - it's the fastest way to implement an acceptable solution

Comment: I will remember for the next time. I will also study your code to understand it perfectly, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you copy the *whole* row from sheet2 to sheet1 like

```
For NxtRw = 2 To LastRw2
    ...
    Sheets(2).Range("A" & NxtRw & ":Q" & NxtRw).Copy _
    Sheets(1).Range("A" & m.Row)
    ...
Next NxtRw
```

? (The rest of the loop should stay the same.)

Comment: Because I need to update the columnA sheet1 from ColumnA sheet2. For exemple:
Case1:
ColumnA sheet2 cell10: MDM-123,MDM345

ColumnA sheet1 cell20: MDM-9999,MDM-5674,MDM-345

Result:
ColumnA sheet1 cell20:
MDM-9999,MDM-5674,MDM-345,MDM-123

Or case2:
ColumnA sheet2 cell20: MDM-9999,MDM-5674,MDM-345
ColumnA sheet1 cell10: MDM345

Result:
ColumnA sheet1 cell20: MDM-9999,MDM-5674,
MDM-345